# Errors caused by the inclusion of NA values in linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, na

I want to do linear regression, but these are NA under one of the conditions. As you can see there are two conditions in my data, S: single and M: married. x2 and x3 are fixed effects and y are the dependent variables. x3 is not applicable for a single condition, so the data is all NA. I don't want to remove x3 as it is an important variable for the married condition. and i recieve this error:

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels.

I tried replacing NA with "0", but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do. Can anyone give me some suggestions? how should i write the lm code?

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c("S", "S", "S", "M", "M", "M"), 
                   x2 = c(7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 2),
                   x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 2),
                   y = c(4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 1))

lm(y~x1*x2*x3, data)
```

Can someone give me some help, please?
(This is also the first time I post, I am not sure if I did it right.)

Comment: Your question might be more suitable for DSSE: https://datascience.stackexchange.com or Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com. A short note on the answer: I would convert NAs to 0s and check the level of significance. As ```x3``` is not applicable to that condition, so making it 0 makes sense too.

Comment: the model is impossible to fix, because you are asking interaction across all the variables. You have to fit a reduced model , for example `y ~ x1 + x2 + x3`

Comment: The keyword is "imputation". Replacing the missing values with zero doesn't make more sense than replacing them by any arbitrary value. replacing them by the mean is sometimes done but not always the right thing to do. Removing rows containing `NA`s is sometimes the right thing to do and you can do it by calling `na.omit()`on your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to bring it to (technical) work, but it isn't so usefull as the others already said

```r
data_df <- data.frame(x1 = c("S", "S", "S", "M", "M", "M"), 
                   x2 = c(7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 2),
                   x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 2),
                   y = c(4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 1))

data_df$x1 <- as.integer(as.factor(data_df$x1))
data_df <- na.omit(data_df)

lm(y ~ x1*x2*x3, data_df)
```